# Qt Signal/Slots in one class but emitted from different threads

Tags: c++, qt

The project is divided in two parts, a library where all processing is done and the GUI. The library is completely in C++/MFC and should not be changed that much because it is also used in none Qt projects which have to be running without Qt dependencies.

The library defines an interface to make calls to an GUI. So the Qt GUI also implements this interface in order to receive the calls from the library. The library runs several threads.
Some of the processing of the GUI calls should not block the library from running. So the GUI class defines slots and signals, the signals are emitted in the implemented interface functions. The signals and slots are connected using:

```
connect(this, SIGNAL(xyz), this SLOT(xyz));
```

I think the problem is that the interface functions that emit the signals are running in `thread A` but the GUI runs in `thread B`. The right way would be create QObjects inside the library and define the signals on that side, but this is not possible in my case. Any suggestions?

Comment: Absolutely no idea what you're asking. Maybe an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would be a good starting point?

Comment: Have you tried connecting with Qt::QueuedConnection?

Comment: first of all, thanks you for you answer, but the library run multi thread without qt ,  how can i emit any signal from any thread of library

Answer (score 1):

In your interface function instead of emitting a signal, use `QMetaObject::invokeMethod()` or `QTimer::singleShot()`.

For `QMetaObject::invokeMethod()` you may need to explicitly pass `Qt::QueuedConnection`.

For `QTimer::singleShot()` set a delay of 0 ms.

Also technically `connect(this, SIGNAL(xyz), this, SLOT(xyz),Qt::QueuedConnection);` and then calling the signal your interface function would work. But I am not a big fan of emitting signals from outside the class. This was not possible in Qt 4 as signals were protected functions, this has changed since Qt 5 as public signals was a necessity for the new connect syntax.

Comment: thanks you for your answer, but the library run multi thread without qt

Comment: I think you can call QMetaObject::invokeMethod() from a non Qt thread.